# How to upload number of images or documents as specified by the users from android using volley?

Tags: android, mysql

My app takes an image (compulsory) and some text and upload the image to the server and saves the image location and text in the mysql database.I want that user can upload multiple images/documents(pdf,doc) as per requirement something like add button to increase the upload fields.
How do I store multiple records in database for each uploaded file(Will I need to create multiple fields for each upload)?
How do I create upload field for new document using add button and implement java for each upload request(user may upload no files)?
and How do I handle this request in php?

My work for uploading single image

```
public class NewsUpload extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button chooseImage;
Button uploadImage;
EditText titleView;
EditText paragraphView;
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;

public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "myurl.com/upload.php";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE ="image";
public static  final String KEY_TITLE ="title";
public static  final String KEY_PARAGRAPH ="paragraph";
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.upload_news);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("username");
    Toast.makeText(this,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    chooseImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    uploadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    chooseImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    uploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    titleView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleUpload);
    paragraphView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.paragraphUpload);
    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageUploadView);
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){
    final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Uploading...","Please wait...",false,false);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(NewsUpload.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError){
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(NewsUpload.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
            String title = titleView.getText().toString().trim();
            String paragraph = paragraphView.getText().toString().trim();
            Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
            params.put(KEY_TITLE, title);
            params.put(KEY_PARAGRAPH,paragraph);
            return params;
            }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = MySingleton.getInstance(this).getRequestQueue(); // Mysingleton => Instance of Volley Class implemented seperately.
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(20*1000,0,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==chooseImage.getId()){
        showFileChooser();
    }

    if(v.getId() == uploadImage.getId()){
        uploadImage();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My app will allow to upload various set of data.Each set will contain some text and number of documents,so how will I uploads those file (as number of files is not fixed).

Answer (score 0):

I've upload my image from phone to NodeJS server
Actually i've not paste all code because, the most import is transmite bitmap to byte

**

```
img_perfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        logout.setText("Guardar Imagen");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                        intent.setType("image/*");

                        startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_OPEN_IMAGE);
                    }
                });



        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


                if (requestCode == RQS_OPEN_IMAGE ||
                        requestCode == RQS_GET_IMAGE ||
                        requestCode == RQS_PICK_IMAGE) {

                    img_perfil.setImageBitmap(null);


                    Uri mediaUri = data.getData();
                   // textInfo1.setText(mediaUri.toString());
                    String mediaPath = mediaUri.getPath();
                    //textInfo2.setText(mediaPath);

                    //display the image
                    try {
                        inputStream = getBaseContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mediaUri);
                        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                        img_perfil.setImageBitmap(bm);
                        img_perfil.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);
                        img_perfil.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,bos);
                        byte[] b= bos.toByteArray();
                        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING);
                        new CargarDatos().execute("CHAT_SERVER_URL"+encodedImage,METHOD_POST);
```

Comment: My question is that suppose i want to upload 3 images/documents now to create a set of data relating each other.But i may upload 5 images/documents using same activity page for other set of data? How will i dynamically control number of uploads since files during one upload are related to each other and saved together?

Comment: In this case I have the same problem probably we can use an array or vector, actually a json